# TypeScript generic T extends Object loose type check

Tags: typescript

say we have code below:

```
function createReactiveObject<T extends Object>(raw: T, handlers: ProxyHandler<T>): T {
  return new Proxy(raw, handlers)
}

function foo<T>(raw: T) {
  // should be error/warn
  return createReactiveObject(raw, {})
}

const sth = foo(1)
```

as you can see , in `createReactiveObject` function we limit that `T` should be a `Object`, but function `foo` doesn't have that limitation, why there is no warn/error that tell me maybe `T` is not Object when we have the code `createReactiveObject(raw, {})`?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQJU9GANzQHkAjAKzWgB4AVRNAD2zABMBnRcq6APgAUKDAHcAXIjoAaRAAsM7ADZoUHCQAUUcJgE8AEgrbKU9PgEoJDAN4AoRInRQQKJGDQjEm7TqGiZ8pRUOMxsAXxsI0EhYBERgODhTX3FJM0Rbe0dnJFRMbDwMAmIeaihkmStQkPCIiAQOKEQG2UQAXjiEgQBGEIibIA)

the title of this question covers a wide range but I don't know how to make it concrete.I'll edit it later.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this document](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object), you shouldn't use `Object` in Typescript. If you still consider using an object type, you can change it to `object`, but it also means you will get an error at `createReactiveObject(raw, {})` because `raw` type is `T` (a generic type which does not match with `object`).

```
function createReactiveObject<T extends object>(raw: T, handlers: ProxyHandler<T>): T {
  return new Proxy(raw, handlers)
}

function foo<T>(raw: T) {
  return createReactiveObject(raw, {}) //mismatched between T and object
}

const sth = foo(1)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQJU9GANzQHkAjAKzWgB4AVRNAD2zABMBnROS6qAPgAUKDAHcAXIjoAaRAAsM7ADZoUHSQAUUcJgE8AEorYqU9fgEpJDAN4AoRInRQQKJGDSjEWnbuFjZCsqqHOa2AL62tqCQsAiIwHBwZn4SUuaIdg5OLkiomNh4GATE5FTQKbLWYekA9DUAtjAc9VgQcmhsiGRoUKJoaEgMRty80OGREAgcUIjTcogAvPGJggCMoZG2QA)

For the generic type check, you need to extend `T` as an object too.

```
function createReactiveObject<T extends object>(raw: T, handlers: ProxyHandler<T>): T {
  return new Proxy(raw, handlers)
}

function foo<T extends object>(raw: T) {
  return createReactiveObject(raw, {})
}

const sth = foo(1) //cannot pass a number into an object type
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQJU9GANzQHkAjAKzWgB4AVRNAD2zABMBnROS6qAPgAUKDAHcAXIjoAaRAAsM7ADZoUHSQAUUcJgE8AEorYqU9fgEpJDAN4AoRInRQQKJGDSjEWnbuFjZCsqqHOa2AL62tqCQsAiIwHBw9IwsaOxcPFTQQiISUuaIdg5OLkiomNh4GATE5FlQfqKy1mGhEbYQCBxQiN1yiAC88YmCAIwFAPQTEIpgcD0ADhgcXBiIYCAAtmSqiDBgUHCIity80IhQugtokZFAA)